# Flutter for web write new tab

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

So I have an html in base64 encoded bytes.

I'd like to do something similar to

```
let pdfWindow = window.open("")
pdfWindow.document.write("<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, " + encodeURI(base64EncodedPDF) + "'></iframe>")
```

in flutter for web. However when I run

```
var openWindow = html.window.open("", "Form");
```

I don't have the ability to write the HTML for the pdf.

My goal is to be able to print the pdf from the browser,

Anyone have any idea where to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Use url_launch package [url_launch](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

```
void main() {
runApp(Scaffold(
body: Center(
  child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: _launchURL,
    child: Text('Show Flutter homepage'),
     ),
   ),
  ));
}

 _launchURL() async {
 const url = 'https://flutter.dev';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
 await launch(url);
 } else {
throw 'Could not launch $url';
 }
}
```